# i have a table in database where i want to get last value of column

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 column in a table where there are many rows. for particular row i have to get the column's last value.so how to get the last date that is 11/10/2013.

```
uid       date         book_id
  1   18/8/2013          41
         to
      11/10/2013
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the last date for a given book_id, you can write something like

```
SELECT MAX(date) FROM myTable WHERE book_id = 41
```

Comment: I am not sure that is what you needed... I first understood you have several lines in your table, containing some dates for `book_id=41`. I understood later that for this particular line "date" field has `18/8/2013 to 11/10/2013`. If my second hypothesis is good, then my proposal is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

You want the latest date entry? Order it descending (latest date first) and limit the resultset to 1.

```
SELECT date FROM table ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1 ;
```

In case you really meant that you've got several dates in one date field and even text also, then you need to change your database schema to something like:

> uid | startDate | endDate | bookID

Comment: What is the poster's problem then?

Comment: The 'date' he is referring to is `18/8/2013 to 11/10/2013`.

Comment: I assumed that this was just a way of showing that there are different dates and he wants to sort them... but in that case there is a database schema problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're storing dates as strings, not as dates. `11/10/2013` is not a valid date, and you'll never manage to sort it properly without using DATE_FORMAT or other functions. That's overkill given MySQL's fine native handling of dates.

Also, if you're storing 2 dates, use 2 columns (for example `date_start` and `date_end`). Never combine them into 1.

Backup your data, change the type of the column to DATE or DATETIME and use `ORDER BY date_field DESC LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you going.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(date,'%e/%c/%Y') DESC LIMIT 1;
--                                ^- the most recent date is first
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: the query which u gave is working but the prob is it is returning the data 30/09/2013 but the last value is 11/10/2013 @alasjo

Comment: Edited my answer to better suit your date format. However, @sherlock gives a better solution for you in the long run.

Comment: thanks for u answer still it show only 01/10/2013. but ans is $end_date is date fetch from db.
    $date_frag = explode("-",$end_date);
    $rev_date = $date_frag[2]."-".$date_frag[1]."-".$date_frag[0];

 when i reversed it start taking from year , month and date it now showing as 11/10/2013

Answer (score -1):

That's how you will do this in php using mysql

```
    $Query = mysql_query(SELECT date FROM table_name ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1);

    $Date = mysql_result($Query,0,'date');

    $Date = explode('to',$Date);
    $Last_Date = $Date[1];
```

Comment: I hope i'll get to know why someone down voted this answer , because the code is definitely working

Comment: thanks for all your answers. 
    answer is 
    $end_date is date fetch from db.
    $date_frag = explode("-",$end_date);
    $rev_date = $date_frag[2]."-".$date_frag[1]."-".$date_frag[0];

 when i reversed it start taking from year , month and at last date.